# Find all HTML sibling element in iOS

Tags: html, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a huge HTML, but at a certain level there are 10 piece of `article` element. I need theme.

```
<article class="box-product-big box-product-full clearfix" >
    <div class="list-left">

        <div class="cover">
            <a id="book_cover_3100529" href="/film/fritz_lang.m-egy-varos-keresi-a-gyilkost-dvd.html">
                                                            <img src="http://s06.static.libri.hu/cover/d4/3/1090228_3.jpg" alt="Fritz Lang - M- Egy város keresi a gyilkost - DVD"/>
                                                </a>
                                </div>
        <div class="desc">
            <a class="book-title" href="/film/fritz_lang.m-egy-varos-keresi-a-gyilkost-dvd.html">
```

..

```
</article>
```

Here is the relating DOM:

[image]

With the following pattern I try to get them, but zero piece returned:

```
var error: NSError?
let pattern = "<article class=\"box-product-big box-product-full clearfix\">[\\S\\s]*?</article>"
var regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &error)!
if error != nil {
    println(error)
}
let a = regex.matchesInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(str)))
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Data comes from here: http://www.libri.hu/talalati_lista/?text=m

---

I tried with different escaping, but get an error:

[image]

> String literals can include the following special characters: The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \ (backslash), \t (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double quote) and \' (single quote)

[doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Comment: The forward slash is not a special character nor a  delimiter in this case. No need to escape it. You may want to check if nsregex needs to have a delimiter _and_ quoted. Otherwise, the regex just may not be finding anything because of whitespace. Something you can try: `"<article\\s+class\\s*=\\s*\"box-product-big[ ]+box-product-full[ ]+clearfix\"\\s*>[\\S\\s]*?</article\\s*>"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a forward `/` which is a special character, so you have to escape it with a backslash using `\/`:

```
let pattern = "<article class=\"box-product-big box-product-full clearfix\">[\\S\\s]*?<\/article>"
                                                  Escape slash with backslash ---------^
```

Quoting the **[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html)**:

> **Regular Expression Metacharacters**
>
> Characters that must be quoted to be treated as literals are *** ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \ . /**

[image]

Btw, you can shorten your regex like this:

```
<article[\S\s]*?<\/article>
```

Code

```
var error: NSError?
let pattern = "<article[\\S\\s]*?<\/article>"
var regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &error)!
if error != nil {
    println(error)
}
let a = regex.matchesInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(str)))
```

Also, you can use capturing groups to capture the content:

```
(<article[\S\s]*?<\/article>)
```

Comment: @János try using two backslashes `\\/` and let me know

Comment: I tried all your suggestions, the escaping you mention is not according to docs, but the shortening and leaving out `class= ..` part helped, even without parenthesis

Comment: @János great, glad to help a little at least :)